# Карточки в три столбца по центру. Данные из json. Как сделать?

Tags: css, json

Имеется json, js сделал вывод данных, но не получается сделать карточки в три столбца по центру. Поможете?
js:

```
let userProf = '<div style="list-style-type: none">';
for (let i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
    userProf += "<div class='main'>" + "<div class='row'>" + "<div class='column'>" + "<div class=\"trigger show-modal\">" + "<h3>" + DATA[i].name + "</h3>" +
        "<br>" + "<br>" +
        "<i class=\"icono-iphone\"></i>" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<span>" + DATA[i].phone + "</span>" +
        "<br>" + "<br>" +
        "<i class=\"icono-mail\"></i>" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<span>" + DATA[i].email + "</span>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "&nbsp"

    ;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userProf;

document.getElementById('search').onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
    let searchText = this.value.toLowerCase();
    let stringLength = searchText.length;
    if (stringLength > 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
            let userName = DATA[i].name.split('').slice(0, stringLength).join('').toLowerCase();
            let userPhone = DATA[i].phone.split('').slice(0, stringLength).join('').toLowerCase();
            let userEmail = DATA[i].email.split('').slice(0, stringLength).join('').toLowerCase();
            if (userName == searchText || userEmail == searchText) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<div class='main'>" + "<div class=\"trigger\">" + "<li class='list' style='list-style-type: none;'>" + "<h3>" + DATA[i].name + "</h3>" +
                    "<br>" + "<br>" +
                    "<i class=\"icono-iphone\"></i>" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<span>" + DATA[i].phone + "</span>" +
                    "<br>" + "<br>" +
                    "<i class=\"icono-mail\"></i>" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<span>" + DATA[i].email + "</span>" + "</li>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<br>" + "<br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userProf;
    }
};
```

css:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}



::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #664AFF
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}

.wrapper .search-input{
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius : 5px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: Opx 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0. 12);
}

.search-input input {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadoW: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.search-input.active input{
    border-radius : 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.search-input .autocom-box{
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius : 0 0 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box{
    padding: 10px 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto ;
}

.autocom-box li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
    display: block;
}

.autocom-box li:hover{
    background: #efefef;
}

.search-input .icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0d6efd;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.trigger {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 340px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #fdfdfd;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(82, 80, 80, 0.78), 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(27, 25, 25, 0.66);
}
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 70%;

    background-color: white;
    padding: 6rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 10;
}
.close-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}





.textcols {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.textcols-item {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 33.33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 100px;
    border-width: 5px;
}
.textcols .textcols-item:first-child {
    margin-right: 100%;
}

.col-3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%; /* Можно задать любую другую ширину блока */
    background: grey;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}



.main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ребята! Разобрался!